# Resharper "unchop if short"

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm looking for a ReSharper command that will take something like this...

```
MethodWithFewerParametersThanBefore(
    param1,
    param2,
    param3,
    param4,
    param5);
```

and convert it to...

```
MethodWithFewerParametersThanBefore(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5);
```

It would be nice if this were built into Code Cleanup without having to turn off "Keep existing line breaks", but I would settle for something that just lets me select the text I want to "unchop" and run a keyboard or menu command.

Is this possible? How?

Note, I found a trick for doing this for the method *definition* (as opposed to the call)--you just do "Change Signature" and change something insignificant. This will reset the parameters to just one line.

Comment: Can't you make custom code formatting profiles for that CTRL E, CTRL C dialog?

Comment: @ta.speot.is, the profile just lets you choose whether or not to "format code", it doesn't seem to let you control details, like "Keep existing line breaks".

Comment: Currently there is no such functionality in ReSharper. Please log your feature requests at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy, thanks, I just added a new request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-338157

Answer (score 0):

Since ReSharper 2017.2: select code, Alt-Enter, Format selection > Compact format.